# How Can I get iOS build version using swift? Ex: iOS 11.3 (15E216)

Tags: ios, swift

Note: I don't want APP Build.

```
 print(UIDevice.current.systemVersion) //OUTPUT "11.3"
```

How can I get the Build String "15E216" ?

Comment: Sorry i dont think so you can get the Build String of the System  Version. @Kamran he is not talking about getting App build and Version number.

Comment: @Shabirjan I saw some app can get it that why I want to get it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the full `string` having `version` and `build` with this line,

```
print(ProcessInfo.init().operatingSystemVersionString)
```

You should get the result in below format,

```
Version 11.3 (Build 15E216)
```